# Amazon Connect Streams Custom Login

Tags: amazon-connect

I need a way to implement amazon connect streams to our custom application.

I have tried amazon-connect-streams library to do so, but i couldnt find a way to bypass the default login which pops up in a seperate tab. Is there a way to create a custom login page for amazon connect streams and use that instead of the default one?

Or is it possible to make an api of our own and serve it to our front end so they can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I also trying to do that, but no wat to do that.

But I got an idea with Dextr.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1IeW8nuH20

Just reverse engineer the process what they have done.
They have used amazon cloud formation service.

I think this will help you.

Best luck

Comment: This does not provide an answer. Please give some points from the source so that answer is sufficient.

Comment: You are right, there is no perfect answer.  but you can take some idea how other guys haw done.